# (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource: Invalid value for field 'resource.rawDisk.source'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gsutil

I'm trying to create a custom image for Google Compute Engine by using a file from Cloud Storage with the following command:

```
gcloud compute images create my-custom-image-name --source-uri gs://my-storage-bucket-name/gce-demo-tar.gz
```

Output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
  - Invalid value for field 'resource.rawDisk.source': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-storage-bucket-name/o/gce-demo-tar.gz'.
    The provided source is not a supported file.
```

The file in question is from a virtual machine exported in RAW format using the following command:

```
VBoxManage clonehd -format RAW ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/SLES12sp5/SLES12sp5.qcow ~/disk.raw
```

Then archived with the following command:

```
gtar -cSzf gce-demo-tar.gz disk.raw
```

However, I'm not sure if the problem is related to the file itself as I have exactly the same error if I try to import an OVA file or it may be related to storage permissions or configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file path when specifying your `--source-uri` flag, try `gs://my-storage-bucket-name/gce-demo.tar.gz`  and make sure the file is uploaded with the same name.

The error might be occurring because of the file extension you tried to use, which is `.gz` and it should be `.tar.gz` instead.

Comment: After renaming the file gce-demo-tar.gz to gce-demo.tar.gz (as suggested) the GCE image creation was successful. Thank you!